# Total Paid Different Than Grand Total

Tags: checkout, payment

When the order is processed for payment the Total Paid is different from the Grand Total.  It appears that the discount is being added back to the Grand Total when charging the customer.

Here is an example:

[image: Screenshot]

I would like to know where I can look to see where the Total Paid amount is set.  We have a custom observer doing some things prior to final check out but have not been successful in getting Magento to charge the correct amount.

Comment: Any idea how to fix it? We are having the same problem atm. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you implement your "doing some things prior to final checkout" not via an observer but as a custom total.

The folks at Classy Llama have a good article to get you started [here](http://www.classyllama.com/content/unravelling-magentos-collecttotals).